# Docker copy files with old modification time

Tags: docker

Is there a way to use the `docker copy` command and keep the modification times from the source, instead of having it change to whenever the copy command was run?

The reason I need this is because after I build the container, I need to run a process (`collectstatic` in a Django app) that copies files over to an S3 bucket.

The process only copies files if the modified time is newer than the existing file mtime in S3.

Since switching to Docker, I'm now having every file being copied when the image is updated because the mtime for the files in the container is newer than the ones in S3.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use files created inside a container from outside the host on a regular basis I suggest you [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) a directory to the container.

You do this when you create the container:

```
docker run -d -v /myfolder:/container_folder image:tag
```

Where `/myfolder` is a directory in your host and `/container_folder` a directory in the container.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately the workflow I want to follow makes this impossible. The entire reason for moving the app to Docker is so that deploys can happen without needing a local copy of the code on the production machines.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you mount the code into the container. Have a directory in common between the host and the container and whatever files you need to copy to S3 from the host, have your application copy it to that shared directory.